# Check for directory at the end of a url in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to add a rule to my apache config that detects a '/confirm/' at the end of any urls and loads the same file with a GET parameter set.

Here's some examples:

```
/page/confirm                        => page.php?mode=confirm
/parent/child/confirm                => /parent/child.php?mode=confirm
/deep/folder/structure/confirm       => /deep/folder/structure.php?mode=confirm
```

This is how I do it for individual files:

```
RewriteRule ^page/confirm?$          /page.php?mode=confirm        [NC,L]
```

Any help would be great, thank you :)

Comment: I've added a comment under the alternate answer to differentiate. Please review this to determine which answer to accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current Rewrite is a good template. To make it apply more universally, can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/confirm/?$ $1.php?mode=confirm [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm pretty sure the issue was because I wasn't including `.php`. I didn't think that I needed it because I have a rule later on that strips the need for file extensions. I realise now because there was an `L` flag it wasn't reaching that rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rewriteRule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/confirm/?$ /$1.php?mod=confirm [NC,QSA,L]
```

The rule will match the following requests :

```
/foo/bar/foobar/confirm
/foobar/confirm/
```

and rewrite to

```
/foobar.php?mode=confirm
```

Comment: Just to differentiate between our two answers. Yours is nearly identical to mine except you use a negated char set for / in your grouping ([^/]+). This will not preserve the full URI which the OP's examples show as a requirement. The standard grouping in my Rewrite (.+) does preserve the full URI.

Comment: @brandonharris you are right, I have corrected the pattern. Thanks.